# Akka remoting message costs?

Tags: java, akka

Is there a way to measure the amout of bytes sent and received by an Akka Actor?
I haven´t been able to find anything related to communication costs.

Comment: Have you thought about monitoring the network? You could use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: My point was to measure communication costs at each node of the system I'm developing

Comment: Wireshark lets you monitor application-specific network traffic, i.e. all traffic occurring on port 2222 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a theoretical way to do this. I didn't test it but it should work. Now you have an actor or set of actors sending messages to remote actors. You should change your model and add a proxy actor. Instead of sending your messages to remote actors directly. You send your messages to this proxy which then routes them to the destination actors. Now that all messages are passing through this proxy. You can do counts and aggregations as you need. I think this approach might add a little overhead to your system but would get you what you need.

Good Luck!